# Extract particular group of a repeating substring with regex

Tags: python, regex

Provided input "inputString" that may take the form "0/1", "0/1/2",... (or any other combination of at least two digits separated by "/"), I wrote the following regex-based expression that extracts the numbers:

```
match = re.search("(\d)+/*", inputString)
```

To list the last two digits, I used

```
match.groups()[-1], match.groups()[-2]
```

However, with "0/1" input, I only get "0". How do I a particular repeating substring (a digit in my case) with regex. Of course, `.split('/')` is an alternative, but I'm interested in regex.

Comment: In your last example - what is the desired output for "0/1" as input?

Comment: You should replace `re.search` with `re.findall`, probably.

Comment: Also, whats the purpose of `/*` in your regex?

Comment: @JonClements Desired is [0, 1].

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes As you can see from the input, it does not end with "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchor your search to the end of the line using `$`.

```
import re

for text in ('0', '0/1', '0/1/2', 'foo', '0/1/2/3', 'bar'):
    m = re.search(r'(\d)/(\d)$', text)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())
    else:
        print('no match for:', text)
```

Gives you:

```
no match for: 0
('0', '1')
('1', '2')
no match for: foo
('2', '3')
no match for: bar
```

At the end of the day though, you'll most likely be better off doing:

```
try:
    g1, g2 = text.rsplit('/', 2)
except ValueError:
    pass # do something appropriate
```

Comment: Given my comment under the original question, I suppose that m = re.search(r'(\d)/(\d)$', text) should have (\d+) (so, with '+')

Comment: @user3560285 adapt as needed - the key point is to anchor your search to the end of line

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `re.findall` instead of `re.search`

`re.search` only checks for a single match, anywhere in the string.

Comment: My pattern should be changed to "(\d+)+/*" from "(\d)+/*", since I'm interested in the whole number. My mistake. Thanks anyway.